# Sharepoint Online - how to search only in one Site

Tags: search, search-results

How to choose to search only one site from many Sites in Sharepoint Online. If I have got many sites I want to choose only one site, from whitch I want to see only one site result.

I need only search from one Site Sharepoint Sites.

..../sites/..
**..../sites/..** <-- I want to search only from this Site. Not the rest sites, how to choose interesting us Site.
..../sites/..
..../sites/..
..../sites/..
..../sites/..
..../sites/..

Comment: Only results from a specific subsite of a sitecollection?

Comment: Specific Site Or Site Collection, but only on Sharepoint Online - so there is only Specyfic Sites

Comment: I have got on Sharepoint Online. to test site. And if i start Search there the result is dubled. Because I use to site test the sime files as production Sites.

Comment: I found what I looking for in this article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25783.sharepoint-2013-working-with-result-sources-to-limit-search-results.aspx